# How to use Due PB0-PB7 pins as an external interrupt

Tags: arduino-due

In my board I need to use PB0-PB7 ports as an external interrupt sources.

Is it possible?

I spent a lot of time to understand that. Seems the easiest way is to update variant.cpp file by adding these pins.

Unfortunately this is not the solution I'm looking for (actually this can be a solution if I'm able to add pins from the sketch, but it is not possible to update cons dynamic array after declaration ).

Another way is to create my own interrupt handler. But I didn't find how should I do that.